# How do I interpret *all factors have a common finite exponent* in this context?

Tags: infinite-product, direct-sum, torsion-groups

"The product of infinitely many torsion groups will no longer be a torsion group unless all factors have a common finite exponent (which is not the case if we take Prüfer groups)."

How do I interpret the words *factors* and *having a common finite exponent* in [this sentence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2774975/what-examples-are-there-of-a-group-in-which-every-element-is-nilpotent-and-has-i#comment5726207_2774975)?

I'm not interpreting it correctly because I'm thinking of any element $x$ of a Prufer group as a factor and they all have having a common finite exponent $e$ by virtue of the group being torsion.

My only hypotheses are a) I'm misunderstanding the words *factor* and/or *exponent*, or b) that the comment relates to the elements and factors of the infinite product/sum rather than of the Prufer group itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if $(G_j\,:\, j\in J)$ is a family of groups, then $\prod\limits_{j\in J} G_j$ is a torsion group if and only if $$\exists m>0,\ \forall j\in J,\ \forall x\in G_j,\  x^m=e_j$$

whereas a family of torsion groups generally only satisfies $$\forall j\in J,\ \exists m_j>0,\ \forall x\in G_j,\ x^{m_j}=e_j$$

Comment: Fabulous, thanks @Saucy .  Not sure I get that rule though.  Torsion-free means it's *not* torsion, right?  i.e. the identity is the only element of finite exponent.  But I read your first rule to say there *does* exists some finite exponent $m$ for every element $x$ of every group, such that $x^m=e$, which would make it torsion :(

Comment: @RobertFrost Yeah, I inverted the terms because I was tired.